# Synology NAS not accessible remotely after move. Possible firewall issue?

Tags: networking, firewall, nas, remote-access

I am a remote administrator for a client who recently moved physical office locations. I'm having an issue with reconnecting back into the Synology NAS that they use for file store. From what they've told me, they are able to access it on the local office network, but are using some unconventional methods in the process. The client moved without any network details beforehand, so I left the configuration as it was and let the client do their thing. Once they got connected back to the internet, the ".synology.me" link I was using to connect to the server now directs to the firewall's login page, which was not accessible before the move and the "quickconnect.to" link now just says the server is unable to connect.

I'm just wondering if there is a firewall rule that I am missing to allow it to connect? Any help or insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Were you using automatic router configuration (i.e. port forwarding initiated by the NAS using UPnP)? Was the router configuration (accessible from Control Panel->External Access) updated to the new situation after the move?

Comment: I did not use UPnP because the router used by the ISP does not support it. And no, the configuration has not been updated since the move. I’ve been able to receive alerts from it via Active Insight and email, I’m just not able to get to the DSM.